# Hbase update use case

Tags: hbase, bigdata

I have the following hbase use case: 
One Hbase table, with a row key (built with a combination of md5 hashes) and 2 column families. Logically, the table stores sentences. The table has hundreds of millions of records.

I have a webapp that connects to this hbase table, and needs to randomly export sentences, based on some conditions. Currently, all these conditions can be looked-up just by using the rowkey. 
Typically, one export would contain just a couple of hundreds sentences. The important restriction is that once some segments are exported, they should not be present in any subsequent export.

So my question is related to this - how should I make sure the same segments do not get exported again?

Should I 'mark' the exported segments, by updating a flag, after each export happens? This has the drawback that, when looking at which segments meet my conditions, I wouldn't be able to use just the rowkey for identifying those records, but also that flag. Hence, I would need to use filters, which I know are way slower.

Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Who passes the row key for you? Can you make sure he sends unique row keys?

If you don't require the data once exported. why not delete that sentence from the hbase table altogether?

If your answer is "no" to both of the above question, then there is no way but to keep a flag in your table.

Comment: I ended up using filters as they seem to be running fast enough for my use case. My only concern is that, let's say, I have some rows to update the flag for. What if, that update is not done(let's say a large number of rows need to be updated), and some other user wants to export data for the same conditions? Will he *see* all the updates? I was reading up [Hbase Acid Semantics](http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html) where I see Hbase is read committed:  "A scan _must_ reflect all mutations committed prior to the construction of the scanner". Does this mean I am safe in my assumption?